# Apache Drill crash immediately on lunch

Tags: apache, apache-drill

I have an issue with my drill cluster, my drill cluster have 1 master node and 4 nodes.

I have stopped each one of drill nodes

```
sudo -i /home/hadoop/apache-drill-1.10.0/bin/drillbit.sh stop
```

and started it

```
sudo -i /home/hadoop/apache-drill-1.10.0/bin/drillbit.sh start
```

I have no clue what to do, have tried searching online but nothing seems related beside this [link](https://community.mapr.com/thread/10249) which didnt solve my issue

```
    2017-07-04 13:09:10,454 [main] INFO  o.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit - Construction completed (2928 ms).
    2017-07-04 13:09:10,864 [main] INFO  o.a.drill.exec.rpc.user.UserServer - User Error Occurred: Drillbit could not bind to port 31010. (Address already in use)
    org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserException: RESOURCE ERROR: Drillbit could not bind to port 31010.

    Server type UserServer

    [Error Id: a75dd2ec-a3b6-4fcb-b60b-0a1a63354943 ]

................
................
org.apache.drill.common.AutoCloseables.close(AutoCloseables.java:64) ~[drill-common-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
            at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.close(Drillbit.java:159) [drill-java-exec-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
            at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.start(Drillbit.java:294) [drill-java-exec-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
            at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.start(Drillbit.java:271) [drill-java-exec-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
            at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.main(Drillbit.java:267) [drill-java-exec-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
    2017-07-04 13:09:11,919 [main] INFO  o.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit - Shutdown completed (1053 ms).
```

Would love to get input for how to solve it

how can i find the reason for this:
Drillbit could not bind to port 31010. (Address already in use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared that i had a zombie task on my ec2 instance locking port 31010

so i killed that pid task
by this:

```
netstat -tulp | grep LIST | grep 31010
```

return

```
tcp        0      0 *:31010                     *:*                         LISTEN      16449/java
```

and now for the finisher

```
kill -9 16449
```